# For some reason, my css will not load on my secure site (but images will) - same static path

Tags: python, css, django, ssl, static

My Platform : Django 1.5.4 , running with a wsgi module in apache

Issue: I am trying to deploy a django site using a secure connection for one route, and for this route, css fails to work (it seems to load though, meaning, the resource is fetched correctly and I can see the code when I go to its path)

I have an alias in my Virtual Host Section on the http.conf file that allows the wsgi to load static files that looks something  like this:
`Alias /static/ /home/username/public_html/mysite/static_dir/`

And, I have a rewrite rule that looks like this so that I can make one of my routes secure:

```
RewriteRule     ^/product/(.*)/buy/$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/product/$1/buy/ [L,R]
```

This works in terms of getting to the secure product page where customers will input credit card info, yet the css will not load correctly. The images will load normally, and they share the thew same path as the style.css that loads.

What's weird is that when I navigate to the css path that is loaded in the head of the page, I see my CSS code!

Here are my static files settings in settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/public_html/mysite.com/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://34.56.78.93/~username/mysite.com/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/username/public_html/path/to/project/static/',
```

and I'm loading the css like this in a  base template `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />`

If you've ever experienced this or have any clue whats going on, please respond. Thanks

Comment: Your `STATIC_URL` is hardcoded to `http:`

Comment: good observation, but that didn't work. It made the images not work as well. The images are using the same static path, and they are loading fine without being https://

Comment: RewriteRules like this one don't help against mixed content, since the redirection happens *after* an initial plain HTTP connection. It's your links you need to check.

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing the STATIC URL to  `STATIC_URL = 'https://mysite.com/static/'` Using the ip address was the issue, also, I added the https:// like you guys  suggested

Comment: You should post an answer and accept it so your question quits appearing as unanswered.